# Trac default language

Tags: python, internationalization, trac

How can I set default language for trac. There's nothing about i18n in trac.ini

Answer (score 1):

Trac will use the locale provided by your http server by default.  Easiest thing to do is just change the locale Apache is running under.

Or if you are running trac under mod_python you can modify the TracLocale option:

SetHandler mod_python
    PythonOption TracLocale "de_DE.UTF-8"
    ...

For more info:
http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFaq#how-do-i-change-the-format-used-for-displaying-date-and-time

Answer (score 0):

The stable release of trac, 0.11.X does not have support for localization. It is added in the upcoming 0.12 which is currently under development. Do you have 0.12 or did you download "latest stable" which is 0.11? In that case you will have to upgrade to get localization support.

The trac site itself appears to be running 0.12 as it is localized.